# Rails and database structuring

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a database of places (labs). Each of them have opening and closing hour.
I am new to this so please comment on everything that you, more experience mate, would do differently.

I decided to create a model called OpenDay with `day:string`, `from_time: Time`, `to_time: Time`.

My main question is related to displaying those days.
Currently the form to insert a database record looks like this:

[image]

If left like in the picture it creates only 2 records in the DB, but it is displayed like this:

[image]

If from_time = 00:00 and to_time = 00:01 then it displayed "closed".

---

Now I want to implement a feature to show every lab that is currently opened and **the question is**:

What would be more efficient - reimplementing the form so 7 records are saved and then do some mysql query to display currently opened labs, or to leave (in this case) 2 records and implement a function like this posted below (that checks for every lab if it is currently opened)? Thanks in advance!

```
def opened_today?(lab)
    weekdays = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
    if !lab.open_days.empty?
        days_hash = {}
        current_day = nil
        weekdays.each do |week_day|
            lab.open_days.each do |open_day|
                if open_day.day == week_day
                    days_hash[week_day] = {from_time: open_day.from_time, to_time: open_day.to_time}
                    current_day = open_day
                else
                    days_hash[week_day] = {from_time: current_day.from_time, to_time: current_day.to_time}
                end
            end
        end
        # Dates variables:
        today = Date.parse(Time.zone.now.to_s).strftime("%A").downcase
        from_time = days_hash[today][:from_time].strftime("%H%M")
        to_time = days_hash[today][:to_time].strftime("%H%M")
        time_now = Time.now.strftime("%H%M")

        if from_time < time_now && to_time > time_now
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I'd create 7 records... just easier.

Comment: Thanks! I will go this way, as you have like 10 more years in experience in Ror